# UItableView Replacing Checkmarks with UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I just want to use `UIButton` instead check marks im successful in adding button and making it working as check mark when row selected but only row selection is working button not wise not i want to make it work button as well as cell selection screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHDfo.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbcKZ.png

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row==0)
{
    if (selectAll==0)
    {
        selectAll=1;
        [self.arrForIndPaths removeAllObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        selectAll=0;
        [self.arrForIndPaths removeAllObjects];
    }
}
else
{
    if (selectAll!=1)
    {
        if([self.arrForIndPaths containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [self.arrForIndPaths removeObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.arrForIndPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        selectAll=0;
        if([self.arrForIndPaths containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [self.arrForIndPaths removeObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {[self.arrForIndPaths addObject:indexPath];}}}[tableView reloadData];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static const NSInteger btnTag = 1;
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"SearchResult";
UITableViewCell *cell;
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 400, 55)];
UIButton *btnCheck = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(845, 10, 35, 28)];
btnCheck.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
btnCheck.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_white.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_white.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_white.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnCheck addTarget:self action:@selector(doneBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnCheck.tag = btnTag;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblText];
[cell addSubview:btnCheck];
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        lblText.textColor =[self colorWithHexString:@"333333"];
        lblText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"VERDANA" size:30];
    }
    else
    {
        lblText.textColor=[self colorWithHexString:@"333333"];
        lblText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"VERDANA" size:20];
    }
}
else
{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        lblText.textColor=[self colorWithHexString:@"333333"];
        lblText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"VERDANA" size:18];
    }
    else
    {
        lblText.textColor=[self colorWithHexString:@"333333"];
        lblText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"VERDANA" size:16];
    }
}
lblText.text=[arrFacilities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lblText.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
if (selectAll==1)
{
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_white.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    if([self.arrForIndPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_white.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_white.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
return cell;
}
- (void)doneBtn:(UIButton*)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean on Cell Selection its working, but on button Click its not working and you want it to work for both button click and Cell Selection.

Comment: still click on cell working but button works (select all button not works ) actually i want same workin to button as working for cell either click on cell or button makes selected as required , Thanks you

Comment: @iDeepak I think your select All is a tableViewCell? right?

Comment: @iDeepak do you need the last tick (tick without square ) for 'select all' cell??

Comment: @Shebin Koshy i need to wok as cell selection , if button will select cell will select and cell will select button also select vice-versa .. button not select image is white square with black borader and selected is blue ticked on box these images i have created shown in screenshots

Comment: @iDeepak i put some codes below. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

globally declare these variables

```
BOOL isSelectedAll;
NSMutableArray *arraySelectedRows;
int allDataCount; // this may be your arrayWithData.count
```

in 'viewDidLoad'

```
isSelectedAll = NO;
allDataCount = 10;
arraySelectedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ce" forIndexPath:indexPath];
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cee"];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
UIButton *buttonSelection = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width - 100, 8, 50, 50)];
buttonSelection.tag = indexPath.row;
if(isSelectedAll)
{
    [buttonSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Rename imageName as yours
}
else if([arraySelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]&&indexPath.row!=0)
{
    [buttonSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Rename imageName as yours
}
else
{
    [buttonSelection setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"untick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Rename imageName as yours
}

[buttonSelection addTarget:self action:@selector(selectionButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:buttonSelection];
return cell;
}
```

in  'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    //select all button
    if (isSelectedAll)
    {
        isSelectedAll = NO;
        [arraySelectedRows removeAllObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        [arraySelectedRows removeAllObjects];
        for (int i = 1; i<allDataCount; i++)
        {
            [arraySelectedRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];//section number may be defer for you
        }
        isSelectedAll = YES;
    }
}
else
{
    if([arraySelectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [arraySelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];

    }
    else
    {
        [arraySelectedRows addObject:indexPath];
    }
    if ((allDataCount - 1) == arraySelectedRows.count)
    {
        isSelectedAll = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isSelectedAll = NO;
    }
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

if you need to do the same thing in button action

```
-(void)selectionButtonAction:(UIButton*)button
{
if (button.tag == 0)
{
    //select all button
    if (isSelectedAll)
    {
        isSelectedAll = NO;
        [arraySelectedRows removeAllObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        [arraySelectedRows removeAllObjects];
        for (int i = 1; i<allDataCount; i++)
        {
            [arraySelectedRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];//section number may be defer for you
        }
        isSelectedAll = YES;
    }
}
else
{
    NSIndexPath *buttonIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];//section number may be defer for you
    if([arraySelectedRows containsObject:buttonIndexPath])
    {
        [arraySelectedRows removeObject:buttonIndexPath];

    }
    else
    {
        [arraySelectedRows addObject:buttonIndexPath];
    }
    if ((allDataCount - 1) == arraySelectedRows.count)
    {
        isSelectedAll = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isSelectedAll = NO;
    }
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The 'arraySelectedRows' contain selected row's indexPath

Comment: Wow Really Awesome , it worked like miracle fixed everything , Thank you VeryMuch Thank you Very

Comment: i have also some issue with making view collapse and expands could you also help me in ????

Comment: already asked here plz look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176153/working-with-one-xib-with-multiple-classes

Comment: i fixed this with little diffrent way but i need your help in some sugestion to make implementation could you tell me how i can contact you ??

Comment: @iDeepak what is the problem now? u have problem in this or in that xib question?

Comment: now implementing a idea i got , doing test 50% succeed now doing rest ... but i need a help of in starting a new project which is for MacOS  Which i dont know how to dealt with it .. thats why thought ask you

Comment: now require suggestion what to do with it .. Thanks for your all Support

Comment: @iDeepak sorry... i too don't know MacOS coding

Comment: no worries , Plz look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198911/how-to-repeatview-over-view-using-array-but-in-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageViewCell *cell =(MessageViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MessageViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell.lblUsername.text  = [arrUsername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *URL =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_URL_IMAGEURL,[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    cell.imgView.tag = indexPath.row;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openProfile:)];

    tap1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    cell.imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [cell.imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap1];

    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"];

    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:cell.imgView];

    cell.imgView.imageURL = URL;

    cell.imgView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgView.frame.size.width/2;

    [cell.imgView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    cell.btnCheckBox.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.btnCheckBox setHidden:false];

    if([[[arrFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"markedToDelete"] boolValue]){
        [cell.btnCheckBox setSelected:TRUE];
    }else{
        [cell.btnCheckBox setSelected:FALSE];
    }


    [cell.btnCheckBox addTarget:self **action:@selector(checkBoxClick:)** forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.lblMsg.text = [arrLastMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
/////
-(void)checkBoxClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblMessages indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)btn.superview.superview];
    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
    if (sender.isSelected)
    {
        arrFriends[sender.tag][@"markedToDelete"] = @YES;
        if(![arrDeleteUsername containsObject:[arrOppUsername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
        {
            [arrDeleteUsername addObject:[arrOppUsername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [arrDeleteUsername removeObject:[arrOppUsername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        arrFriends[sender.tag][@"markedToDelete"] = @NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for button click action does not look to do any thing. Just add the following code to your project and it should work:

```
- (void)doneBtn:(UIButton*)sender{
if ([sender tag]==0)
{
    if (selectAll==0)
    {
        selectAll=1;
        [self.arrForIndPaths removeAllObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        selectAll=0;
        [self.arrForIndPaths removeAllObjects];
    }
}
else
{
    if (selectAll!=1)
    {
        if([self.arrForIndPaths containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]])
        {
            [self.arrForIndPaths removeObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.arrForIndPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        selectAll=0;
        if([self.arrForIndPaths containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]])
        {
            [self.arrForIndPaths removeObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]];
        }
        else
        {
         [self.arrForIndPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]];
        }
       }
    }
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Or make the changes accordingly.

Comment: Make sure you are setting button tag correctly instead of tag you have added.

Comment: im using button.tag = indexpath.row , anyother suggestion Thank you Verymuch for your Reply

Comment: it fixed add set button.tag = 0 , only selecting button make all button selected but it needs to one at a time (select all will select all at time ) , anyother suggestion , Thansk Alot

Comment: Thanks for your all Effort i realy appreciate it ..not worked tried this , still selecting all on cliking button otherwise cell selection is working good  , can it not be done same as cell selection is working ???

Comment: hello , still waiting for reply how could i fix this