# UItableView Replacing Checkmarks with UIButton or custom CheckImage for Multiple Selection

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I have already asked a question [UItableView Replacing Checkmarks with UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875235/uitableview-replacing-checkmarks-with-uibutton/31876766)

but not got solution till now , anyone will provide me solution ??
1.make this button as cell selectable 
or 
2. want to change default checkmark with my custom image

but funtion needs to work as it is

thanks in advance

Comment: this is easily done by subclassing a UITableViewCell, I don't have time right now to show you the answer, but I'll post something very soon, basically, instead of Using "UITableViewCell * cell = " you register a custom cell class like "CCSTableViewCell" and use it the same way you would like the UITableViewCell, so instead of "UITableViewCell * cell = ", you have "CCSTableViewCell * cell = ", the custom CCSTableViewCell is the parth that will take some time, but it's all manageable.

Comment: when you create your subclass, you assign it a property BOOL value that will be either TRUE or FALSE, obviously, and then when the cell is selected, the BOOL value changes to TRUE and then this triggers a custom image to show up on the cell, done and done, that's how you do it

Comment: and in fact, here, I'll post a custom cell for you, and there you go, this will be your answer, just do things normally, but when you click that cell, you must grab the indexpath.row, and send the message to the underlying tableviewcell.

Comment: thanks for reply but im new to ios development waiting for your post

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a full custom, UITableViewCell

```
#import "NSHCellStuffTableViewCell.h"

@interface NSHCellStuffTableViewCell ()
@end

@implementation NSHCellStuffTableViewCell
{
    UILabel * nameLabel;
    UILabel * mainLabel;
    UIButton * cellIcon;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self==nil)
        return nil;

    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:32 saturation:100 brightness:63 alpha:1]];
    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18.0f]];
    [nameLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:nameLabel];

    mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [mainLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [mainLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:66 saturation:100 brightness:63 alpha:1]];
    [mainLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18.0f]];
    [mainLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:mainLabel];

    cellIcon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cellIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_IMAGE_WHEN_CELL_IS_NOT_SELECTED"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cellIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_IMAGE_WHEN_CELL_IS_SELECTED"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [cellIcon setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:mainLabel];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, mainLabel, cellIcon);
    NSDictionary * metrics = @{@"hello" : @13, @"goodBye" : @25};

    [[self contentView] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hello-[cellIcon(goodBye)]-hello-[nameLabel]" options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [[self contentView] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hello-[cellIcon]-hello-[mainLabel]" options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [[self contentView ] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cellIcon]|"  options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [[self contentView ] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-hello-[nameLabel]-hello-[mainLabel]-hello-|"  options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

    return self;
}

-(void)setNameText:(NSString *)nameText
{
    _nameText = nameText;
    [nameLabel setText:_nameText];
}

-(void)setMainText:(NSString *)mainText
{
    _mainText = mainText;
    [mainLabel setText:_mainText];
}

-(void)setCustomSelector:(BOOL)customSelector
{
    _customSelector = customSelector;
    [cellIcon setSelected:_customSelector];
}

@end
```

NSHCellStuffTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NSHCellStuffTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) NSString *nameText;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *mainText;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL customSelector;

@end
```

So, here's how it works

you have to import **"NSHCellStuffTableViewCell.h"** into your UIViewController

you have to then register this class in your ViewDidLoad like this:

```
[tableView registerClass:[NSHCellStuffTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YOUR_CLASS_IDENTIFIER"];
```

Then, you do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
      NSHCellStuffTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSHLessonCellLargeIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell setCustomSelector:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

NSMutableArray *chechBoxList;

```
chechBoxList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<CountOfTable; i++) {
              [chechBoxList addObject:@"0"];
       }
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:-

```
[cell.checkboxBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckBoxSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.checkboxBtn setTag:indexPath.row];
if ([[chechBoxList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

    [cell.checkboxBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else{
    [cell.checkboxBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


button CheckBoxSelection:-

-(void)CheckBoxSelection:(UIButton *)sender{
 if ([sender isSelected])
 {
    [chechBoxList replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"0"];
    [self.tableViewUninvitedFriend reloadData];
    [sender setSelected:NO];
}
else
{

     [chechBoxList replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"1"];
     [self.tableViewUninvitedFriend reloadData];
     [sender setSelected:YES];

}
}
```