# How is a table view with circular images, titles, subtitles, and extra labels to the right built?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I am trying to figure out exactly how the view pictured below is made, with the circular image holder, titles and subtitles:

[image]

Comment: UITableView can be used with custom cells.

Comment: This question is too broad as it is. You need to separate it. Circular image masking and custom table view cells are different stories.

Comment: @jtbandes thank you for response. So it's just a UITableView with custom cells? How did they go about implementing the line that divides each cell to not go all the way the the edge and cuts off?

Comment: @Desdenova So as for the circular image masking, you can't implement via UITableView with Custom Table View Cells?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/separatorInset

Comment: It's not that circular image masking is incompatible with table cells, it's that they are entirely unrelated topics. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503

Comment: you make that bottom line with constraints using a custom UITableViewCell, you just use the formatting language like this @"H:|-40-[bottomLine]|"

Comment: @jtbandes thank you so much for the quick responses! I'm going to dive right in and start learning! You the best!

Comment: @Larcerax thank you! Do you know what kind of formatting that is called? Would love to learn more about it

Comment: yeah, you have to create  a bottomLine in a custom UITableViewCell, you do this UIView * bottomLine = [UView new]; [bottomLine setTranslatesAutoResizingMask:FALSE]; [bottomLine setBackGroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]; [[self contentView] addSubview:bottomLine];

Comment: then, you do  [[self contentView]  addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[bottomLine]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];  [[self contentView]  addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[bottomLine(0.5)]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

Comment: @Larcerax  Is there any way you could provide a screenshot of it showing with them in it? Still not quiet getting. Sorry :( a slow learner

Comment: I made this custom UITableViewCell in like 5 minutes, just add a bottom line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132970/uitableview-replacing-checkmarks-with-uibutton-or-custom-checkimage-for-multiple/32133497#32133497

Comment: @Larcerax Hello. Sorry for the late response but I attempted and I am getting an error 'Use of undeclared identifier 'unmetrics'', and 'No visible interface for 'UIView' declared the selector 'setTranslatesAutoResizingMask'. Under which method and .m file am I supposed to include it in? And how about as for the .h for that particular .m, do I need to add anything to .h? Thank you in advance!

Comment: ahh yea, so you have to decalre your own metrics, that's why, i'll show you in a bit

Comment: @Larcerax thank you!! I will wait so once you have done so please tag me :D. Really excited to implement it already

Comment: @Larcerax Checking up to see if you had the chance to do it. Please let me know! Thanks in advance~

Comment: oh crap, Ko ki, let me see what i can put together for you

Comment: is this in objective c or swift?

Comment: @KoKi also, Koki, is this storyboards or raw code?

Answer (score -1):

```
cell.yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
cell.yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

Comment: thank you but could you clarify where those code belongs to and what they do?

Comment: @SantoshReddy Please consider adding some detail to your code.